# Rails 4 ckeditor file upload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor in my rails projec and I have a problem with image uploading.
I don't want everything that ckeditor have, that I wrote some simple config.js for it:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = (config) ->
  config.language = 'pl'
  config.toolbar_Pure = [
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   items: [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
    { name: 'links',       items: [ 'Link','Unlink' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles',      items: [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors',      items: [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'insert',      items: [ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','PageBreak' ] },
  ]
  config.toolbar = 'Pure'
  true
```

and in my view:

```
= f.input :answer, label: false, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'Pure'} }
```

And with this config I don't have a button to select image from my computer:
[image]

But when I delete my config.js and in view set:

```
= f.input :answer, label: false, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'Full'} }
```

then I have the button to upload file from my computer and everything works fine. Now my goal is to edit my config.js to have this file upload working. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I change my config to:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
  config.language = 'pl';
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  config.toolbar_Pure = [
    '/', {
      name: 'basicstyles',
      items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']
    }, {
      name: 'paragraph',
      items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl']
    }, {
      name: 'links',
      items: ['Link', 'Unlink']
    }, '/', {
      name: 'styles',
      items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']
    }, {
      name: 'colors',
      items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor']
    }, {
      name: 'insert',
      items: ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'PageBreak']
    }
  ];
  config.toolbar = 'Pure';
  return true;
};
```

and works as expected