# How to upload image using CkEditor and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'v installed this https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails lib into my Rails application. 
I would like to use CkEditor image upload functionality, but i'dont know how to write the backend logic, how to handle request, save file and send a response back to CkEditor to display uploaded image.

The CkEditor's configuration is the following:

```
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
      language: 'en',
      filebrowserImageUploadUrl : "/upload",
      filebrowserUploadUrl : "/upload",
  });
```

Rails function

```
def upload
  @func_num = params["CKEditorFuncNum"]
  @ck_editor = params["CKEditor"]

  render :layout => false
end
```

Comment: I believe you are trying to eat more than you can. There are mote gems like CkEditor, but more user friendly. Try [**Rich**](https://github.com/kreativgebiet/rich)

Comment: I think you will get a solution from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928348/rails-4-ckeditor-file-upload)

Comment: Piggy backing on @RareFever You might want to look at [Bootsy](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy)